# How to Create a Firebase Cloud Function Triggered by New Repository Commits?

Tags: typescript, git, firebase, github, google-cloud-platform

I'm working on a project where I want to set up an automated system that performs certain actions in response to new commits made to a repository. Specifically, I'm using Firebase, and I'd like to create a Firebase Cloud Function that gets triggered whenever there's a new commit to my repository on GitHub .

I'm not entirely sure how to go about setting up this automated workflow. Can someone provide guidance or steps on how to create a Firebase Cloud Function that listens for new repository commits and then takes some specific actions based on these commits?

To clarify, I'm looking for information on:

```
How to set up a Firebase Cloud Function.
How to configure it to listen for new commits to a repository.
How to extract information from these commits (e.g., commit messages, authors, etc.).
How to trigger custom actions based on the commit data.
```

Any code examples, tutorials, or best practices related to this use case would be greatly appreciated. I'd like to implement a robust and efficient solution, so any insights or advice from experienced developers in this area would be invaluable.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to create a Firebase Cloud Function that gets triggered whenever there's a new commit to my repository on GitHub.

Looking at the list of all [triggers for Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling), there is no native trigger for Cloud Functions built into GitHub.

What you could do is create a HTTP endpoint in Cloud Functions and then call that from a [GitHub web hook](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads). A quick [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=github+webhook+cloud+functions) leads to some promising results and articles on that.